# How to pre-loading all document symbols for vscode remote project?

Tags: visual-studio-code, remote-server

is it possible to pre-loading all document symbols in remote project?
In default, it just loading symbols when you open the file. If you do not open the corresponding document, the reference will not be displayed correctly. Which force me to use global search.

How to set pre-loading symbols for remote project?